# CupertinoSliverRefreshControl in NestedScrollView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In my app i need complex scroll views. As horizontal lists inside of vertical list and animated headers. The code below is a minimalistic sample that makes my problem reproducible on iOS devices.

I have problems with nested scrollviews in flutter. if i use **SliverOverlapAbsorber** and **SliverOverlapInjector** the used **CupertinoSliverRefreshControl** (the progress indicator) doesn't show up on pull down.

So i replaced it with a red Container. It seams like it's shifted to the top so it's below the appbar.
When I set pinned to false in the SliverAppBar it's showing correct, but i need the appbar to stay. I don't get what the pinned parameter has to do with that.

Also, if i put less items in my SliverFixedExtentList (let's say 5 instead of 50) the CupertinoSliverRefreshControl it's not possible to pull down at all (no scrolling, also only not working with the overlap observer/injector used).

***Can anyone help me, why this is happening or has an alternative for the overlap observer/injector?***

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class TestScrollRefresh extends StatefulWidget {
      const TestScrollRefresh({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<TestScrollRefresh> createState() => _TestScrollRefreshState();
    }
    
    class _TestScrollRefreshState extends State<TestScrollRefresh> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: NestedScrollView(
            headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isBoxScrolled) {
              return [
                SliverOverlapAbsorber(
                  handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context),
                  sliver: SliverAppBar(
                    title: Text("Title"),
                    forceElevated: isBoxScrolled,
                    pinned: true,
                  ),
                ),
              ];
            },
            body: Builder(
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                final innerScrollController = PrimaryScrollController.of(context);

            return CustomScrollView(
              controller: innerScrollController,
              slivers: <Widget>[
                _refreshIndicator(),
                SliverOverlapInjector(
                  handle:
                      NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context),
                ),
                SliverFixedExtentList(
                  itemExtent: 48.0,
                  delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                    (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return ListTile(title: Text('Item $index'));
                    },
                    childCount: 50,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<bool> refresh() async {
    print('wait for service to refresh dummy');
    await Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 5000));
    return false;
  }

  _refreshIndicator() {
    return CupertinoSliverRefreshControl(
      onRefresh: () => refresh(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, RefreshIndicatorMode refreshState, double pulledExtent, double refreshTriggerPullDistance, double refreshIndicatorExtent,){
        return Container(color: Colors.red,);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to address this issue by using the builder property of CupertinoSliverRefreshControl:

```
        CupertinoSliverRefreshControl(
          onRefresh: onRefresh,
          builder: (context, refreshState, pulledExtent, refreshTriggerPullDistance, refreshIndicatorExtent) {
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
              child: CupertinoSliverRefreshControl.buildRefreshIndicator(
                context,
                refreshState,
                pulledExtent,
                refreshTriggerPullDistance,
                refreshIndicatorExtent,
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
```

This [GitHub comment](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36419#issuecomment-853513411) also helped me better understand the usage of NestedScrollView.

Comment: It's sadly just a workaround. 
As i see it its a flutter bug, I thought I might oversee something.
I am already using a builder and of course this is possible, as I mentioned in my question that the Container is painted behind the Appbar, without the Safe area.

In reality I am using a complex SliverAppBar with dynamic height, so instead of the Padding in your example, I have to use a Column and build my complex Appbar inside the Column again in a Visibility Widget. 
Also the problem, that I can not use the refresh when my list is too small is still not solved.